# Check if number is not between 2 values

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below to check if a value is outside of a set range (e.g. not between 1 and 300).

My formula looks to work when I try testing numbers at the range limits, for example...0 triggers the if statement, 1 does not trigger the if statement, 300 does not trigger the if statement, 301 triggers the if statement

However, when I try numbers 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 the if statement is also triggered and I can’t understand why.

When I try random numbers from 1-3 and 10 +, the if statement is not triggered as I would expect.

```
 var minNumber = 1
 var maxNumber = 300

 if(minNumber > numberValue || maxNumber < numberValue){     
      notValid = true;
      var errorText = "Number out of range, please enter a number between 
      " + minNumber + " and " + maxNumber + ".";
      showErrorMessage(formElement, errorText);
 }
```

Comment: `!(numberValue > minNumber && numberValue < maxNumber)`

Comment: How do you determine that  *"the if statement is also triggered"* ? Your snippet does not contain any logging/printing/output/anything.

Comment: Sorry had missed off a call to a function that displays the error message, now updated

Comment: Solved, my number value was a string value, i have now added Number() to the select .. var numberValue = Number(this.value);

Answer (score 3):

According to your if condition block,you want a condition that works when numbervalue is not between 1 and 300,so you have to change your condition a little bit like below...

> !(minNumber > numberValue && maxNumber <
>   numberValue)  //change

so your code become like this...

```
if(!(minNumber > numberValue && maxNumber < numberValue)){     
  notValid = true;
  var errorText = "Number out of range, please enter a number between 
  " + minNumber + " and " + maxNumber + ".";
  showErrorMessage(formElement, errorText);
}
```